# What is the best dictionary for texmaker?

Tags: math, latex, texmaker

I using texmaker for writing I noticed that the dictionary is missing a lot of scientific words that MS word would never miss. Is there a better dictionary similar to what in MS Word.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most often, the dictionary (en_US.dic and en_US.aff) will be located in 
`>/ur/share/hunspell/`

In Texmaker, In

```
Options/Configure Texmaker/Editor/Spelling Dictionary
```

load the 'en_US.dic' file.

If it is not there, do as following:

Try this link to get the latest updated dictionary http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/english-dictionaries-apache-openoffice

Download the .oxt file. Extract the files and then Open texmaker and in

```
Options/Configure Texmaker/Editor/Spelling Dictionary
```

load the 'en_US.dic' file.

And, if you need, look here as well : http://www.swisswuff.ch/wordpress/?p=166